# Модальные окна, на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

пытался реализовать модальные окна на сайте их 3 , проблем лишь в том , что после клика на кнопку закрытия, повторное открытие какого-либо модального окна сопровождается с **ошибкой:** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var modalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-open-modal'),
        overlay = document.querySelector('.js-overlay-modal'),
        closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-modal-close');
    modalButtons.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var modalId = this.getAttribute('data-modal'),
            modalElem = document.querySelector('.modal[data-modal="' + modalId + '"]');
            modalElem.classList.add('active');
            overlay.classList.add('active');
        });
    }); 
    closeButtons.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            var parentModal = this.closest('.modal');
            parentModal.classList.remove('active');
            overlay.classList.remove('active');
            parentModal.remove('#vid');
            overlay.remove('#vid');
        });
    });
    document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        var key = e.keyCode;

        if (key == 27) {

            document.querySelector('.modal.active').classList.remove('active');
            document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.remove('active');
            document.querySelector('#vid').remove(this);
            document.querySelector('#vid').remove(this);
        }
    }, true);
    overlay.addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.querySelector('.modal.active').classList.remove('active');
        this.classList.remove('active');
    });
});




<div class="modal" data-modal="3">
   <svg class="modal__cross js-modal-close" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"               viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M23.954 21.03l-9.184-9.095 9.092-9.174-2.832-2.807-9.09 9.179-9.176-9.088-2.81 2.81 9.186 9.105-9.095 9.184 2.81 2.81 9.112-9.192 9.18 9.1z"/></svg>
   <form class="form" method="POST" action="">
       <label>Телефон</label>
       <input type="tel" placeholder="введите телефон">

       <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Я согласен с обработкой личных данных
       </label> 

       <button class="request__main button">
           Перезвонить
       </button>
   </form>
</div>
```

пример верстки модального окна

```
<a href="#" class="js-open-modal" data-modal="3">
                    <div class="header__call">
                        заказать звонок
                    </div>
                    </a>
```

пример реализации кнопки вызова модалки

не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Физически перенесите скрипт ниже HTML... Когда выполняется JS, браузер еще не знает, что после него есть какие-то HTML-элементы.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME файл со скриптом подключен перед </body>

Comment: Значит добавить ему атрибут `<script src="..." defer>`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME добавил, проблема осталась (

Comment: приведи в вопросе пример, который можно запустить. Проблема, скорее всего, заключается в том, что ты удаляешь лишний элемент, который потом пытаешься найти, чтобы добавить класс

Answer (score 0):

Cоздайте одну общую функцию для показа и скрытия модальных окон, и ниже потом вызывайте эти функции с аргументами каждого модального окна.